# 'Log group does not exist' when AWS Glue fails

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I'm using jobs from AWS Glue for very fist time, so it is normal that my job does not work but I can't see any detail log about what is wrong, because when I click in "Error Logs" link, or in "Logs" link I always get this message in AWS CloudWatch:

```
* Log group does not exist
The specific log group: /aws-glue/jobs/error does not exist in this account or region.

* An error occurred while describing log streams.
c.substring is not a function
```

How can I see AWS Glue Logs? Doesn't AWS Glue create the log group automatically?

Comment: Couple of things : Check the role that used along with your Glue job has permission to create and write to CloudWatch logs. Also the issue can be that your Glue job failed even before writing anything to CloudWatch. Update your question with the error message received from Glue

Comment: I'm using a role with arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchFullAccess policy so I guess It should be able to create CloudWatch logs

Comment: If you have proper permissions and still unable to write to logs means that there is no log generated before the job started to fail. If possible can you update your question with exact error and the script used?

Answer (score 1):

Check if your IAM role has AWSGlueServiceRole policy attached to it or not, once you have verified a log is placed at the right position before the failure occurs.